# Permissions denied when trying to use ldid

Tags: xcode, compilation, entity, code-signing, cydia

I am trying to use ldid to sign an app for cydia.  I got ldid from https://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/detail?name=ldid in order to sign for armv7.  I keep getting denied permissions when trying to use it.  I logged in as root, used sudo, and actually dragged the file in to make sure it was getting the right file.  Should I chnage the permissions of the file?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the problem was.  I used `chmod -R 777` and now it works

Comment: this is the fix if you are getting `/opt/theos/bin/ldid: Permission denied`